# jQuery-ui didn't delete element in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is there any different syntax to implement delete event in `jquery-ui` for Firefox than in Chrome? In Chrome item is deleted from the list, in Firefox is not - https://monosnap.com/file/ZzjCmECmNUjT7fAA8vlmkAhaCN0Nf1

**fileUpload.js**

```
$(document).on('click', '.remove', () => {
  currentUploadFiles--;
});

$(document).on('click', '.removeFile', function () {
  $(this).closest('.alreadyUploaded').remove();
});
```

**_file_upload.html.erb**

```
<td class="delete bank-employees-users-registration__file-table__remove">
  <button class="delete remove bank-employees-users-registration__file-table__remove-delete" data-type="{%=file.delete_type%}" data-url="{%=file.delete_url%}">
    <%= image_tag "icon_close.svg", alt: "Close icon", class: "bank-employees-users-registration__file--delete" %>
  </button>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't see an element with class "removeFile" in the HTML you posted.

Comment: Pretty sure there isn't.